# Is there a way to make the IBM JVM use standard RFC cipher suite Names?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

All IBM cipher suite names begin with SSL_ even though standards say some should begin with TLS_. Is there an option to make the JVM use the standard names so I dont' have to create special include/exclude rules to get Jetty 9 to work with SSL? An option that does this is mentioned in the following link but I can not find any doc on what the option name is or how to set it.
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=9b5a56a9-fa46-4031-b33b-df91e28d77c2

The IBM J9 JVM only allows interop with the RFC names when declaring the precise list of Cipher Suites to use.

In other words, it wont ever return the RFC names in the supported lists, but will use the RFC names when you declare what you want to use.

This decision by the IBM J9 JVM is incompatible with many projects.

When using the IBM J9 JVM you have to declare the entire list of Cipher Suites you want to use with any product that uses an SSLEngine on the IBM J9 JVM. (HTTP Clients, WebSocket Clients, REST Clients, HTTP Servers, etc...)

On Jetty, you will need to create a custom `SslContextFactory` to behave in the IBM J9 JVM way, not using RFC Name patterns for inclusion / exclusion.  Override the following method and implement it your IBM J9 JVM way.

```java
public SSLParameters customize(SSLParameters sslParams)
{
    super.customize(sslParams);
    _selectedCipherSuites = // String[] of selected cipher suites on IBM J9
    sslParams.setCipherSuites(_selectedCipherSuites);
}
```

And alternate approach, that would be more wholesome, is to create a new registered security provider (say "myIbmRFC") that can return a `SSLContext` which uses the RFC names.

It would have to support ...

```java
String protocol = "TLS";
String provider = "myIbmRFC";
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol, provider);
context.init(....); // read javadoc about this
SSLParameters enabled = context.getDefaultSSLParameters();
SSLParameters supported = context.getSupportedSSLParameters();
// these two should return RFC names (a mapping between IBM and RFC)
String[] enabledCipherSuites = enabled.getCipherSuites();
String[] supportedCipherSuites = supported.getCipherSuites();
```

> Note: You cannot use HTTP/2 on IBM J9 JVM.  The  [`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` Cipher that is mandated by the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-9.2.2) cannot be discovered, so it winds up failing the HTTP/2 initialization.  If you do manage to get past this, then the list of [Blacklisted Cipher Suites from the HTTP/2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#appendix-A) use the RFC names as well, and cannot be overridden, so that will increase your likelyhood of generating a `INADEQUATE_SECURITY` from the remote endpoint to a near certainty as you will be using a blacklisted Cipher suite that wasn't excluded by Jetty's HTTP/2 layer.